# Why are tank cars cylindrical?

Tags: rail

Hold height constant. Then a Rectangular Prism, with length and width = radius of the cylinder, has greater volume! So why aren't tank wagons (railroad vehicles that transport gas and liquid)  Rectangular Prisms?

[image]

Comment: But how well does that shape support loads like pressure and bending?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- A cylindrical structure will have a lower surface-area to volume ratio than any other shape that will fit in the structure gauge of railway infrastructure.
- I can't be certain but that tank looks as though it has been formed by continuously rolling a continuous helical coil from a flat strip. This lends itself to a continuous process of coiling, welding (with the seam passing by the fixed welder) and then chopping the "pipe" into wagon sized lengths.
- The cylinder will be very strong. It appears from the photo that the tank is self-supporting. No need for chassis so there is further weight saving.
- Possibly the weight of the full tank results in close to the maximum axle loading. A bigger tank couldn't be filled (although a shorter wagon could be built).
- The cylindrical shape eliminates all corner stress points and seams except for the end caps.

Comment: I left my comment so the OP could learn for themselves by doing a bit of research - instead of handing out to them on a plate...

Comment: OK, Mike. I didn't read it as a homework question and if I had I would have prompted the OP through the thought process.

Comment: This isn't homework. Thanks for your assistance.